# I want to save text, numbers, and dates to a jdbc database error thrown "java.language.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java, database

```
private void btnAClientActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    String s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format( 2017/03/26);

    try {
        String dateString = "2017-03-26";
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date myDate = formatter.parse(dateString); //changing date format

        String insert = "insert into Clients values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        //PrepareStatement to insert into database     
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(insert);         
        ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(textID.getText()));
        ps.setString(2, textFirstName.getText());
        ps.setString(3, textLastName.getText());
        ps.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(textHmd.getText()));
        ps.setString(5, dateLpayment.getText());
        ps.setString(6, textPayment.getText());
        ps.setString(7, dateNpayment.getText());
        ps.setString(8, textSup.getText());
        ps.setInt(9, Integer.parseInt(textHmdpm.getText()));
        ps.setInt(10,Integer.parseInt(textWeight.getText()));
        ps.setInt(11,Integer.parseInt(textCweight.getText()));
        ps.setInt(12,Integer.parseInt(textBmi.getText()));
        ps.setInt(13,Integer.parseInt(textGbmi.getText()));
        ps.setInt(14,Integer.parseInt(textHeight.getText()));
        ps.setString(15,dateSD.getText());
        ps.setInt(16,Integer.parseInt(textGweight.getText()));
        ps.setString(17, dateBirth.getText());
        ps.setInt(18,Integer.parseInt(textBweight.getText()));

        //Trying to retrieve data from textfields and DateChooserCombo to
        //insert into jbdc database.
        ps.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Saved");
    }                                          
    catch( HeadlessException | NumberFormatException | SQLException | ParseException e) {
        ///Trying to catch errors thrown especial the NumberFormatException.               
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

I am trying to save text, numbers, and dates to my database but I keep getting the same error no matter what I have tried. I have searched StackOverflow and the internet for the answer and again, nothing seems to work.

Comment: one of those fields you're trying to turn into a number is a blank string. Integer.parseInt() can't accept that as a valid number

Comment: Please post the rest of the exception you are receiving. I suspect what you've added in the question title is not the full message.

Comment: The only exception is the one I put in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You send a value as a parameter, which can't convert a number, to `Integer.parseInt()` method. The parameter of `Integer.parseInt()` must be able to convert to a number or else it throws NumberFormatException.

For Example:

```
ps.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt("1235"));
```

this code will work.

```
ps.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt("abcd"));
```

But this won't work. Because `"abcd"` cant convert a number.

Comment: I tried ps.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt("12345"));      But I still got an error. How would I go about accepting information from a date field and then parsing the number provided by the date field?